# Python убрать 0 из переменной

Tags: python

Имеется скрипт на python который подтягивает информацию о OpenNebula (в моём случае, нагрузку на процессор какого-либо хоста). Информацию о хосте заносит в переменную
`percentage_used_cpu = percentage(used_cpu_host, max_cpu_host)`.
Вывод:

```
50.0
43.8
22.7
88.8
82.8
54.2
53.3
41.2
30.3
50.3
60.6
61.9
64.6
57.1
70.8
59.6
68.3
100.0
0.0
68.8
37.5
25.0
67.5
34.2
42.5
```

Как я могу убрать тут 0.0 ? Потому как у меня есть функция:

```
def percentage(used, max):
    return round(float(used / max * 100), 1)
```

Которая ругается, при делении на 0.
По итогу мне нужно либо как-то убрать 0, либо просто сделать так что бы скрипт пропускал эту ошибку.

Comment: `return round(float(used / max * 100), 1) if max else 0`? Кст, `max` неподходящее название переменной т.к. совпадает с названием встроенной функции https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max. Лучше переименовать :)

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо огромное, помогло !!! Если правильно понял, то конструкция такая: "Если max еще 0 "

Comment: можно же было просто добавить в функцию проверку на 0

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так чтоб не было ошибок. Это избавит и от других непредвиденных ситуаций

```
def percentage(used, max):
    try:return round(float(used / max * 100), 1) 
    except: return 0
```

Comment: лучше не ловить все ошибки, а только `ZeroDivisionError`